# ui-ListView refresh cells

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, listview, onsen-ui

For a PhoneGap (iOS) app I'm trying to implement a long scrollable list of names. I'm using Onsen UI and found a dynamic list view module that's compatible with this UI:
http://stevenlambion.github.io/ui-listView/

Now, I got it to work, but I have a problem while scrolling the list. When I hold my finger down and drag the list, new items (cells) pop-up just fine. However, when I 'throw' the list in a direction (the continuous scroll thing), new cells won't appear until it has stopped scrolling. While testing this on the ui-listview website, I don't have this problem.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, this was caused for me by position: fixed, that does not work on ios, you have to somehow figure out how to do it with position: absolute. Here is some reference: [iOS7 position:fixed; works ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545981/ios7-positionfixed-works-ugly)